# Java 7 Issue reading character by character

Tags: java, string

I need to be able to manipulate each character in a string. Could someone tell me what I'm doing wrong here?

```
import java.io.*;

public class encryptedWrite {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            File file = new File("code.txt");

            // if file doesnt exists, then create it
            if (!file.exists()) {
                file.createNewFile();
            }

            BufferedReader read 
                = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
            int charNumber = 0;
            String content = read.readLine();
            FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(file.getAbsoluteFile());
            BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(fw);
            String numberString = charNumber + "";
            String modCont = content.charAt(numberString);
            while (!(modCont.equals("#"))) {
                bw.write(modCont);
                charNumber++; 
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

I need to be able to output each character of content to code.txt.

Comment: what output are you getting, and why is it wrong? We can't read your mind.

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple issues that I see. First, charAt takes a numeric argument, not a String argument.  Second, you need to read inside the loop, not outside.  I would replace:

```
    String modCont = content.charAt(numberString);
               while (!(modCont.equals("#"))) {
    bw.write(modCont);
        charNumber++; 
      }
```

with

```
while (true) {
    String modCont = (String) content.charAt(charNumber);
    if (modCont.equals("#")) {
        break;
    }
    bw.write(modCont);
    charNumber++; 
}
```

Comment: I did this and it shows an incompatible types error in String modCont = content.charAt(charNumber);

Comment: A cast should take care of that, and I modified my question appropriately.  Alternatively, you could make `modCont` a `char` and adjust the rest of the code accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

The String's class method: charAt() takes an int as argument, you are passing a String object as argument.